# parallel query execution in mysql

Tags: mysql, c, load-testing

I made chat messenger in C.
Now iam writing load generator in c to check capacity of my server.At first stage iam testing for mulitple signups from clients all running parallel at a time,server takes their requests and runs mysql query but it fails to signup for maximum clients
Like for 10 clients running in parallel atmost 2 and 3 are getting signed up and rest of them returned unsuccesfully.
Multiple clients are made using threads.

Comment: What errors are you getting. What does this have to do with Workbench?

Comment: Questions about tuning the database configuration for high performance are probably more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com. SO is for programming questions.

Comment: You probably already know this, but MySQL connections aren't thread safe. You need one connection per thread.  Most people load testing DBMSs write a simple client program in a high-level language, then spawn it many times in many processes. Or you could spawn a whole mess of shell programs running the command-line `mysql` client.

Comment: But if i create new connection per thread there will be a usage of lot of cpu resources One more thing when iam trying to check for my authentication requests for multiple clients all running parallel i get response from mysql server that "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" it is happening even for 2 parallel select queries.
Authentication request is just a select query at database side . Is there any solution other then creating new connection per thread

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Parallel Query execution in Mysql ,please go through below .  MySQL natively supports any kind of multi-threading. There is concept called sharding that may help you. This requires that you install a plugin for running.

more information and a Shard tool can be found here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/07/increasing-slow-query-performance-with-parallel-query-execution/

Comment: *...supports any kind of multi-threading...*. True, but each MySQL "thread" runs in the context of its own client connection. Client connections aren't thread safe, and only run one query at a time.